# Can linearity be expressed by a modal logic formula?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Can I write a modal logic formula that describes linearity? by linearity I mean the following properties:

- reflexive
- transitive
- $\forall{x,y} \;\; (xRy \lor yRx)$

I'm thinking on it for over a day and I guess it's not possible. If it is how and If it is not why?

Comment: for total relations $ \forall x,y (xRy \lor yRx ) $ something like: $ ( \Diamond P \land \Diamond Q )  \to ( \Diamond  (P\land ( Q\lor \Diamond  Q)) \lor \Diamond ( Q  \land \Diamond P) ) $  maybe simpler formulations exist.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't think that's an answer to my question. thanks anyway.

Comment: @Willemien I tried to verify that, but one side seems to be very hard to prove: "the given formula forces all models to have totality". do you have a proof for that? I guess I successfully proved the reverse.

Comment: @Willemien Also, do you say that the given formula is consistent with `T` and `4` axioms?

Comment: Thinking about it totality is impossible to to prove. It is impossible to proof the absence of an unreachable world. it is independent of $T$and $4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "describes" you mean "modally defines" (i.e., there is a modal formula $\varphi$ such that for every frame: the frame satisfies the property iff the $\varphi$ is valid in the frame), then the answer seems to be no: By the Goldblatt-Thomason Theorem (see e.g. Blackburn, de Rijke, Venema, [Modal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=pbb_Asgoq0oC&pg=PA142) (2002) p.142) modally definable classes of frames need to be closed under disjoint unions. This is not the case for the class of frames satisfying $\forall x,y \;(xRy \lor yRx)$.

However, the slightly weaker property
$
\forall x,y,z\;(xRy \land xRz \rightarrow (yRz \lor zRy))
$
**does** turn out to be modally definable over the class of reflexive and transitive frames by the formula $\Box (\Box A \rightarrow B) \lor \Box (\Box B \rightarrow A)$, see e.g. Hughes, Cresswell, [A New Introduction to Modal Logic](http://books.google.at/books/about/A_New_Introduction_to_Modal_Logic.html?id=Dsn1xWNB4MEC&redir_esc=y) (1996), p.128 and p.175.

The logic of both of these frame classes is modal logic [$\mathsf{S4.3}$](http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/structures/systems/s4.3.html).

Comment: thank you, good answer and useful links.